# Show specific posts with WP_Query using ACF Post object

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I need help with this one. What I want to do is to display specific posts of the custom post type.
Everything working fine, just I can't display more than 1(one) post. doesn't matter how much posts I select it always return to me just one.
Here is a full code

```
<?php

$post_objects = get_sub_field('choose_blocks');
$string = "";
if( $post_objects ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object):

        $post_id = $post_object->ID;

        $string .= $post_id.',';


    endforeach; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $string =  rtrim($string, ','); ?>

 <?php
     $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'presentations',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'post__in' => array( $string )
    );
?>
 <?php // the query
    $all_presentations = new WP_Query($args); ?>

    <?php if ( $all_presentations->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( $all_presentations->have_posts() ) : $all_presentations->the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->


        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
       <!-- do nothing -->
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

now we are getting there.. you really need to try to explain, what your problem is, its not very clear in your question.

my assumption is, you tried this one, but it didn't work out:

```
foreach( $post_objects as $post_object):
  get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_format( $post_object->ID ) );
endforeach;
```

and here is why: you call the template, but the global `$post` is still set to the previous post/page. you need to set the global `$post` variable as you do it later on in your code (`$all_presentations->the_post();`). it works differently, when you do it in a foreach and not with `WP_Query()`, but you can set the global `$post` variable when you hand and object of that post to [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata). when you do that, you can call all the other functions, like `the_title()` or `the_content()` and wp will grab it from the object, that you provided.

here is how:

```
<?php
 /**
   * when you call the_title() here, it will return the title of the current post/page (global $post defined by main query)
   */
if( $post_objects ):
  foreach( $post_objects as $post): //!!the variable MUST be called $post
    setup_postdata($post); //set new $post_object
    /**
      * now we switched global $post, so the_title() will return other the contents of your $post_object
      */
    get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_format() );
  endforeach;
  wp_reset_postdata(); //reset global $post
endif;
?>
```

you need to call `setup_postdata()`on your obect, to use `get_post_format()`. see the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) for more info on setup_postdata.

Comment: Thank you for your time. OBJECT doesn't contain post_format, that i really need for calling that specific template. Basically i use same `php` that you write, and that give me no result.

Comment: that is correct, the object does not contain the post_format. but with the ID, that is inside $post, it will be able to get it.. foreach is running? do you get the ids when you simply run `the_ID()` in there..?

Comment: see my answer once again, i edited it to be more clear about what is going on. if that is not your issue, create a new question and post the link here, since it tends to get confusing with too many comments and editing questions and ansers..

Comment: Definitely i will try your code when i go back to that project this month. This solution will help me a lot with future projects :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution, i need to returns an array of string. It's not enough to pass string in array()

```
<?php $arr = explode(',', $string); ?>
```

Full code

```
<?php

$post_objects = get_sub_field('choose_blocks');
$string = "";
if( $post_objects ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object):

        $post_id = $post_object->ID;

        $string .= $post_id.',';


    endforeach; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $string =  rtrim($string, ','); ?>


// THIS IS THAT I NEED TO GET IT WORK
<?php $arr = explode(',', $string); ?>


 <?php
     $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'presentations',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'post__in' => array( $string )
    );
?>
 <?php // the query
    $all_presentations = new WP_Query($args); ?>

    <?php if ( $all_presentations->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( $all_presentations->have_posts() ) : $all_presentations->the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->


        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
       <!-- do nothing -->
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Or instead of setting `$string` as a `string` variable, you can just make it an `array`. That way, you don't need to do the `explode()`-ing. :) See [this](https://pastebin.com/Z9Ez37LP) (find all the `$string` on that page). And btw, in your code, you forgot to change the `array( $string )` to `$arr`.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Why are you performing another query for posts that you already have? The posts you have are already in `$post_objects`, you don't need to do another `WP_Query`.

Comment: I was actually going to ask the same question @JacobPeattie. Stefan, you could really just loop through the `$post_objects` you have and display the post anyway you like. There's the `setup_postdata()` function if you need to call `the_content()` or similar 'the_xxx'/'get_the_xxx' functions for the current post.

Comment: @SallyCJ
I do like this because $post_object don't have value in array about post_format. Also get_post_format() didn't work even if i pass ID of specific post. So i need to do this like this. If you know how to do this i will be more then grateful!

Comment: @honk31
Thank you for your words. Everything is true what you said, but the OBJECT doesn't contain post_format, that i really need for calling that specific template

Comment: @JacobPeattie Check my replays

Comment: Mind your language @honk31. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: @Stefan *If* I can, I would see if I can do something that might help you with that. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Correct, if you can, it would help me a lot ;-)
BTW, i search google as well, don't think i just want from someone to help me and share his/hers knowledge with me because i'm too lazy. Also i found answer about this one from 2014, and still no change [link](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/filter-a-post-object-by-post-format/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Stefan. I don't actually really understand this: "*$post_object don't have value in array about post_format*", but `get_post_format( $post_object->ID )` should return the proper post format, if post formats are supported by the active theme.  But anyway, what I was going to say are already in honk31's (good) answer, so all the best. =)